# Select all data from current month and next month from MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I cant figure out how to make this work, i tried a lot of different ways but i didn't found working one, so please help me :)

my current query looks like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `police` 
WHERE skadenca BETWEEN DATE(now()) 
  AND adddate(current_date, interval +1 month) 
  AND produkt LIKE 'avto' 
  AND statusobnove=0 AND status=0
```

so just like i already said i want to grab all data from current month and next month.

ty

Comment: Current calendar month or +/- 30 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to understand your question.

*Between current date and end of next month* would phrase as:

```
where 
    skadenca >= current_date 
    and skadenca < date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 2 month
```

*Between the start of current month and the end of next month* would be:

```
where 
    skadenca >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')
    and skadenca < date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 2 month
```

*Between the current date and one month ahead* would be:

```
where 
    skadenca >= current_date
    and skadenca < current_date + interval 1 month
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for fast reply :) looks i was not clear enough..so i have about 100 rows, about 60 are from december ( different days ) and about 40 they are in january ( different days )...so i want to grab them all from both months

Comment: @user2352034: the second expression does that.

Comment: i tried but it grabs only rows in december

Comment: @user2352034: my bad. Fixed.

Comment: now works like a Mercedes :) thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu